# Do action based on whichever # is picked

Tags: python, random, numbers, action, generator

Lets say i have this code at the bottom. Its really annoying if I need to change something. Is there an easier to way write this code? Something with arrays or idk? I'm pretty new to Python so any help would be appreciated.

```
    ti = randint(1,10)

    if ti == 1:
        something.action()

    if ti == 2:
        something2.action()

    if ti == 3:
        something3.action()

    if ti == 4:
        something4.action()

    if ti == 5:
        something5.action()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary to map your keys to the functions you want to run:

```
>>> def func1():
...     print(1)
... 
>>> def func2():
...     print(2)
... 
>>> mydict = {1: func1, 2: func2}
>>> 
>>> ti = 1
>>> 
>>> mydict.get(ti)()
1
>>> ti = 2
>>> mydict.get(ti)()
2
>>>
```

Or using your example:

```
mydict = {1: something.action, 2: something2.action}
ti = random.randint(1, 2)
mydict.get(ti)()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map your functions to a dictionary:

```
# the dictionary
# the keys are what you can anticipate your `ti` to equal
# the values are your actions (w/o the () since we don't want to call anything yet)
func_map = { 
    1: something.action,
    2: something2.action,
    3: something3.action
}
ti = randint(1, 10)

# get the function from the map
# we are using `get` to access the dict here,
# in case `ti`'s value is not represented (in which case, `func` will be None)
func = func_map.get(ti)

# now we can actually call the function w/ () (after we make sure it's not None - you could handle this case in the `else` block)
# huzzah!
if func is not None:
    func()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list of class instances:

```
import random
class Something:
   def __init__(self, val):
      self.val = val
   def action(self):
     return self.val

s = [Something(i) for i in range(10)]
print(s[random.randint(1,10)-1].action())
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a [switch statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement), something that isn't natively supported with Python.

The mapping functions to a dictionary solution mentioned above is a great way to implement switch statements. You can also use if/elif which, I find easier and more readable for one-off implementations.

```
if case == 1:
    do something
elif case == 2:
    do something else
elif case == 3:
    do that other thing
else:
    raise an exception
```